# Are there any error messages or penalties for including a .css page with link rel that does not exist?

Tags: php, css

I'm using a live Joomla site and I want to include a page_title.css inside the template, but I was wondering if I could just include the link even if the stylesheet doesn't exist, without error messages or search engine penalties.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_title.css" />
```

If page_title.css didn't exist there wouldn't be any problems, right?

Comment: Why include it if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Because there are hundreds or even thousands of pages and it takes me a very long time to find the location of the content, and I don't have access to everything, but I need to edit the css on particular pages.

Comment: @ Matt if you are referencing the same .css or .js on hundreds or thousands of pages you're probably doing something wrong.  Sounds like the perfect use case for a masterpage or partial view depending on what platform you're running.

Comment: Have you thought about applying an id attribute to the body tag and using that as a hook in your CSS instead?

Comment: @cobolstinks No, actually it's smarter to have a consistent theme and reuse the same .css files for hundreds of pages, in my opinion.

Comment: @Matt I don't mean to get into a best practices war, but how I do this is in MVC3 is through partial views.  So my partial view has all my default css and js that is needed on all my pages, one reference to these files not hundreds or thousands, than when UX drops a new css i update the single file... It works either way i just dont want to waste time looking for references.  You can and should reuse global css files, but you shouldn't have thousands of references to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines won't typically care about CSS (or js) files or the like, so there should be no 'penalty' there.

On your web server, there will be the 404 errors for requests for CSS files that do not exist. Those could stack up to a fairly significant statistic. For someone like me, that would bother me, but maybe you don't care as much.

(Per the comment added by [ernie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759517/ernie), note that there is also some server load associated with these 404 requests/responses)

As for the browser, it will try to load a non-existent CSS file, but no browsers will popup any error messages or anything of the sort. The rest of your styles will be applied properly, though.

Comment: Related to the 404 errors, those could also stack up to be non-trivial server load, depending on the traffic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could check to see if it [exists](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_exists.asp) and then include it if it does

Answer (score 0):

Its really up to the browser on how it handles this situation.  Most of the modern ones wont be affected by sourcing a non existent CSS or JS file.  I can't speak to the SEO aspect of your question however.

Its still not a good practice to include non existant files.